# Get arguments of function expression (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

This is for network library I'm working on (ActionScript3). I saw this concept in other library (player.io).. Don't have full access to code, so I'm trying to figure out how it was done. I like the way it looks, easy to understand and simplifies the process so trying to get something similar done.

```
var myclass:Connection = new Connection(ip, port); //create new connection
//move is packet ID

myclass.addMsgHandler("move", function (x:int, y:int):void
{

bob.x = x;
bob.y = y;

});

myclass.addMsgHandler("attack", function (mob:String, atk:String, dmg:int):void
{

mobDict[mob].hp -= dmg*atk;

});
```

So then I clearly write out my packets like that, and what to do when I receive certain ID...

Inside Connection class what needs to be done:

```
public function addMsgHandler(id:*, listener:Function):void
{
//get id, add it to packet id list...

//figure out parameters of listener (example: x:int, y:int)
//if I encounter the id "move" in tcp stream expect 2 integers

//for example mob:String, atk:String, dmg:int
//expect 2 strings in stream after "attack", probably will have to look for /0 to know where string ends
//also expect dmg 4 bytes......

}
```

Not sure how complex it will be to implement but the library I took a peek at seems to be doing that.. Maybe I misunderstand how it works but that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no difference between these two:

```
myclass.addMsgHandler("move", function (x:int, y:int):void{ });
```

and

```
myclass.addMsgHandler("move", moveHandler);

function moveHandler(x:int, y:int():void { }
```

You just pass a reference to a function.

Second - I can't think of a way to fully get what the parameters of the function are. You can use `length` property to check their count. But I don't think you can get their type.

That's why the best way is to give a typed object (class) as a property. This way your `Connection` class can make simple checks what's going on (`if (handler == MoveHandler)`), and you will know exactly what to do and how many arguments you've got.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `describeType()` on a class to get access to all of its methods, including parameters and return type. So this:

```
trace( describeType( this ).toXMLString() );
```

would return something like this:

```
<method name="addChild" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="flash.display::DisplayObject">
  <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
</method>
```

You could parse your class, then depending on the string name of the function that you pass, you'll know what to read.

Unfortunately for method closures, it returns something like:

```
<type name="builtin.as$0::MethodClosure" base="Function" isDynamic="false" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="Function"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <accessor name="length" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="Function"/>
  <accessor name="prototype" access="readwrite" type="*" declaredBy="builtin.as$0::MethodClosure"/>
</type>
```

which isn't very useful, as it doesn't pass any of the info that we need. You could probably work something out along the lines of:

```
public function addMsgHandler( event:String, obj:*, funcName:String ):void
{
    // 1) parse obj (you'd only need to do this once per class, as it's not quick)
    // 2) find the definition of obj[funcName]
    // 3) read the params etc
    // 4) add the listener - obj[funcName] is a Function object
}
```

That being said though, most server libs send a pre-defined object, where each message is either prepended by the length (recommended) or terminated by a null byte.

In your case, your object might look like:

```
public class ServerMsg
{
    public var event:String = null;
    public var success:Boolean = false;
    public var attachment:* = null;
}
```

Then you dispatch your events in normal signal/event listener style - it's still as clean, arguably cleaner - each callback only needs to take one parameter of type `ServerMsg`, and the specific parameters are only known by the object that needs them (i.e. your `Connection` class doesn't need to know that `attack()` takes two `Strings` and and `int`)

Comment: Hit submit prematurely? :P

Comment: haha, yeah - I keep hitting tab when writing the examples :D Thought SO would still keep that you'd edited it, but apparently not

Comment: I would strongly recommend not using describeType as it's extremely slow. But I agree with your latest part, stating it should be sending typed objects :) (as I also wrote) Cheers!

Comment: yeah, `describeType()` isn't something that you want to be doing all the time, but it's pretty trivial to cache the results in a `Dictionary`, so you only do it once for each class. And, if you know the classes that you're going to be working with, you can pre-cache them in a "loading" state or something

Comment: If you know your classes it's best to simply make if statements for that particular class. Using describeType here will make such an abstraction that I cannot even imagine. But yes, sometimes it's helpful :)

Comment: what sort of language would this be if we couldn't work around a problem in a ridiculously complicated fashion? ;)